# Spring Boot recuperar valor del controlador y mostrarlo en un Modal

Tags: java, spring, modal, controller

Lo que necesito esal cargar un Modal que este muestre una serie de valores. Actualmente estoy probando solo con uno, un String de prueba.

**Este es mi Modal:**

```
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                  Launch demo modal
                </button>
                
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">¿Desea cargar la información en el proyecto?</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body" id="areaValue">
                                <table>
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <th class="tableHeader">Rol</th>
                                        <th class="tableHeader">Matrícula</th>
                                        <th class="tableHeader">Usuario</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <th><strong>JdP</strong></th>
                                        <th><strong th:text="${proyecto.matriculaJdP}"></strong></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**Este es el código javascript que necesito completar para que muestre en el modal la respuesta del controlador:**

```
<script>

    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    modal.onclick = function(){
        
        $.get( "/proyectos/selenTmp", function( data ) {
        
            window.alert(data);
            
            
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Error');
        });
    };

</script>
```

**Y por último este es mi método de prueba que devuelve un String que quiero mostrar en el Modal:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selenTmp", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String pruebaSelene(ModelMap modelMap){

     return "Test";
}
```

Este Método se encuentra dentro del controlador del Proyecto:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/proyectos")
public class ControladorProyectos {
```

Necesitaría saber el código javascript para comincar el Modal con el Controlador, he buscado por todos lados pero no encuentro nada. Gracias por adelanteado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el modal esta precargado con datos fijos podrías rellenar la información directamente en Thymeleaf con un `th:each` en la tabla.

Si la información es dinámica se pueden hacer varias formas

1. En el método del controlador poner la anotación `@ResponseBody`. Esta anotación hará que el controlador en vez de devolverte una vista te devuelva un JSON o un String únicamente(En tu caso devolverá solamente 'test'). El método quedaría así:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/selenTmp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public String pruebaSelene(ModelMap modelMap) {

       return "Test";
   }
   ```

   Una vez recibida la información deberás implementar código en JS con una lógica para añadir los datos al DOM que en tu caso deduzco que será añadir nodos a la tabla del modal.
2. La segunda opción sería que el fragmento de la tabla estuviera en un HTML aparte y en vez de devolver un texto o un objeto devuelvas esa vista como haces con cualquier otra del controlador(con su objeto `ModelAndView` o `Model`). Al ser una petición AJAX el controlador renderizará la vista con la información y te la devolverá como un HTML completo, una vez recibida solo deberás insertar el texto HTML en el nodo que tu quieras, ejemplo suponiendo que devuelvo la parte de la tabla, aunque se podría devolver el modal entero

   ```
   $.get("/proyectos/selenTmp", function(data){

      $('#areaValue').html(data);
      $('#exampleModal').show();//para abrir el modal

   }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
      console.error(error);
      alert('Error');
   });
   ```

Yo te recomiendo usar la primera opción por ser mas correcta.

Comment: Hola Manuse, gracias por tu pronta respuesta: efectivamente, la información se debe cargar de forma dinámica, y es esta parte que comentas "Una vez recibida la información deberás implementar código en JS con una lógica para añadir los datos al DOM que en tu caso deduzco que será añadir nodos a la tabla del modal." la que no sé hacer.

Comment: Lo acabo de volver a revisar y funciona!! gracias amigo!